# What if lightweight process model (like in Erlang) is used in paravirtualized sub-OS?

Tags: erlang, operating-system, virtualization

What if web-server would be implemented like this:

1. Host OS, Linux for example
2. Virtual machine in which this sub-OS is started (paravirtualization)
3. Lots of lightweight process for each connection in this sub-OS that get interact with outness through sub-OS system calls

?

In this case

1. No process-food in host system
2. Isolation - it keeps working fine, whatever happens in virtual machine
3. We start native complied apps and "let it fail" in case something goes wrong. Or shutdown even the hole virtual machine.

Comment: Erlang based OS was developed along Eralng VM and Mnesia years ago. It didn't work because OTP team could not keep up with hardware/driver layer. AFAIK the idea was not so bad. Erlang style processes and database instead of filesystem

Comment: Better now than never. I think this may interest you: http://erlangonxen.org/

Answer (score 0):

Handling network traffic inside a virtualized environment always causes problems with performance of the network input/output operations. See for example this post: [Basecamp, now with more vroom](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/1819-basecamp-now-with-more-vroom)

All incoming HTTP requests would need to be redirected by the host operating system into specific virtual machines. This would cause constant switching of context between these paravirtualized operating systems and additional overhead on network I/O operations.

```
Host OS receive a HTTP packet -> copy the packet to the VM's memory -> switch to the VM process -> inside the VM: receive the packet in the sub-OS network stack -> copy the packet to the receiving process (the web server) -> switch to the receiving process -> handle the request and return a response (with the same steps in reverse order)
```

This could be fine for the mentioned additional benefits but would require extra hardware to handle the same traffic when comparing to standard solutions.

In Erlang its Virtual Machine isn't a separate operating system with its own network stack but instead is a standard process running on the hosting operating system natively. There is no overhead on IO network operations as they are all handled by the host OS.

```
Host OS receive a HTTP packet -> copy the packet to the Erlang VM's memory -> switch to the Erlang VM process -> handle the request and return a response
```